# SQL. XML values from column. How to get?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

For example I have table "BigApple" with three columns.

- first column includes numbers
- second column includes some text
- third column includes XML files.

My question is: how to get to the third column of the specific values for a particular tag?

Comment: By "XML files" you mean xml tags saved as text? Can you provide sample file and what do you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the XML methods on XML column https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you have the same kind of XML data in the third column you can read specific tag values easily.

Please refer to examples on [SQL XML query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/microsoft-sql-server-xml-query-example.aspx) using a single XML variable
and example to [query XML column in SQL database table](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/query-sql-server-database-table-xml-data-using-cross-apply.aspx) using CROSS APPLY

Answer (score 0):

Mao, how do you expect to get an answer which really helps you without showing your data? It can be trivial 'til really tricky to get data from an XML. Do you need only *one particular tag*? Or are there several data? Nested data?

One example for a trivial read might be this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl(Number INT, SomeText VARCHAR(100),SomeXML XML);
INSERT INTO #tmpTbl VALUES
 (1,'Test1','<root><a>xmlA1</a><b>xmlB1</b></root>')
,(2,'Test2','<root><a>xmlA2</a><b>xmlB2</b></root>');

SELECT Number
      ,SomeText
      ,SomeXML.value('(/root/a)[1]','varchar(10)') AS Tag_a 
FROM #tmpTbl;
GO

DROP TABLE #tmpTbl;
```

The result

```
Number  SomeText    Tag_a
1       Test1       xmlA1
2       Test2       xmlA2
```